# Xamarin Forms WebView and EvaluateJavaScriptAsync

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview

There is a Xamarin Forms project. This project has one "MainPage" page.

This is the markup for `MainPage.xaml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="TestApp.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <WebView x:Name="web" Source="<my_domian_here>" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200" />
        <Button Text="Click Here" Clicked="btn1_Clicked"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

The code for `MainPage.xaml.xs`:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TestApp
{
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        async void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            try
            {
                string elementValue = await web.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("document.getElementById('element-id').value;");

                await DisplayAlert("Element", elementValue, "OK");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace + "\n" + ex.Data, "Close");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I click on the button, I get the error

> The type initializer for 'System.Random' thread an exception.

when running `EvaluateJavaScriptAsync` (the WebView itself is loaded). Please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: There is no System.Random in your snippet.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Hi , have you solve that , whether the Alert shows when you click the button?